# Fiber tape changer missing on lsscsi

Tags: ubuntu, scsi, fiber, bacula, tapedrive

I'm configuring a server with Bacula to manipulate backups on a Dell TL4000 connected to the server via Fiber.

During the configuration of the Bacula Director I've accessed the `bconsole` to see if the configuration was being applied. Once I've exited the console, the `lsscsi` stopped showing the `mediumx` (changer) on the list. It shows the two drives, but nothing about the changer and, before entering the console it showed the changer.

I've tried restarting the `TL` and using `rescan-scsi-bus`, but nothing too.
Anyone have a clue about this?

I'm using Ubuntu Server 16.04.3, and installed Bacula via `apt-get`.

Answer (score 1):

I just found out that, on the Library Type configuration on the `TL` are two options: Random and Sequential. I've changed it to sequential, thinking that it was going to force the Library to use the tapes in the numbered order. This option make the changer disappear on the server. I tested change this option back and forth and everytime it is on Sequential the changer disappear.

Comment: Yes. This is intended behaviour. If you have an application that cannot handle a tape changer sequential means that once you unmount a tape the next one will be loaded automatically. In that mode you cannot manage tapes via the `mediumx` changer, so it isn't exposed to your host.